# Can I build a list of Strings using each constructor of a class?

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have a simple data type such as:

```
data Class = Class1
           | Class2
           | Class3
           deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Is there a simple way for me to build a list of Strings that contains the String version of each of these such that:

```
func Class = ["Class1", "Class2", "Class3"]
```

Comment: Sort of... What is the type of `func`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, but with a caveat. What is the type of `func`? It looks like its first argument would be a type, not a value. More on the later...

---

Deriving `Enum` gets you get the ability to list off successive constructors and deriving `Bounded` gets you the ability to get the "first" and "last" elements of this enumeration.

```
data Class = Class1
           | Class2
           | Class3
           deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Bounded)
```

Then, we can get a list of all the elements via `enumFromTo minBound maxBound` (or just `[minBound .. maxBound]`).

However, back to the initial question on the type of `func`. You need to pass in a type as an argument. The usual way of doing this is using `Proxy` and `ScopedTypeVariables`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

func :: forall a. (Enum a, Bounded a, Show a) => Proxy a -> [String]
func Proxy = map show $ enumFromTo minBound (maxBound :: a)
```

Try this out at GHCi:

```
ghci> func (Proxy :: Proxy Class)
["Class1","Class2","Class3"]
ghci> func (Proxy :: Proxy Bool)
["True","False"]
```

Comment: While your answer is more education, and perhaps more complete, I've accept the other only because it accomplishes my needs more simply. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: I don't think the other answer satisfies the conditions set in the question.  If you can already use "Class1" why not use all others as well?

Comment: @karakfa Was your comment maybe intended for the other answer? I don't see how it applies here...

Comment: This is much better than my answer, so I'm going to delete it (my answer, that is).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'll accept Alec's answer since you believe it to be better, but I think it's worth leaving yours up for posterity.

Comment: @FutureShocked Okay, I'll leave my answer, then :)

Comment: @Alec, I was suggesting that this answer is the right one and commenting to the OP's earlier choice and comment.

Comment: Minor quibble: since you don't actually use the `Proxy`, it's usually better to give a type like `... => proxy a -> ...` (note the lower-case `p`) and a definition like `func _ = ...`. This lets the caller use any collection they may have lying around, which is often syntactically cheaper than cooking up an appropriate `Proxy`; e.g. if you have an `[a]` or `Set a` or `Map k a` or `IO a` or whatever lying around, you can just pass it rather than having to bring the type variable `a` into scope and then write the clumsy `(Proxy :: Proxy a)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could, perhaps, do something like this:

```
data Class = Class1 | Class2 | Class3 deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

GHCI:

```
Prelude> fmap show $ enumFrom Class1
["Class1","Class2","Class3"]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @FutureShocked I think Alec's answer is much better. You should accept it instead of mine.